# Date Output error in Batch Script only on the 8th

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I current run the below script to get the current day minus 1 and the current month.  It works great for all days and month except for the 8th of every month and August of every year. I have to change the script to setting it manually for August. Does anyone know why and is there a fix.

```
SET m=%date:~4,2%
SET /A m -= 1

SET m=0%m%

REM ****** SET m=08 this was used because the date was not right ******

REM SET m=08

SET currMon=%date:~4,2%/%date:~10,4%

REM ****** SET PriorMon=12/2017 this was used for Year End because the date was not right ******

REM SET PriorMon=08/2018

SET PriorMon=%m:~-2%/%date:~10,4%
```

Comment: This is not the correct way do get the previous day. Let me post a proper way for you as answer.

Comment: It also crashes on 09.  Plenty of questions and answers on StackOverFlow that are about date math.

Comment: Number strings starting with `0` are interpreted as octal numbers. `08` and `09` are invalid values in octal system. For that reason these two invalid values are replaced by `0` on evaluation of the arithmetic expression. There are really dozens of answers showing how to work around unexpected interpretation of a value with a leading `0` as octal number. And there are really dozens of date maths related answers on Stack Overflow, too. It is always a good idea to first research before starting a development and re-invent something which others have already coded perfect and published.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hybrid *vb/batch* script. It is a proper way to get the date `-1` or whatever amount of days you want:

```
@echo off
set day=-1
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\*%~n0.vbs"
set "yyyy=%result:~0,4%"
set "mm=%result:~4,2%"
set "dd=%result:~6,2%"
set "final=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%"
echo %final%
```

I simply echo the final result here which as far as today's date goes (for me as it is the 7th) should echo `06-09-2018`

You can change the format of `%final%` as you please to suit your date..

Answer (score 0):

Proper date calculatons in pure batch [are possible](http://ritchielawrence.github.io/batchfunctionlibrary/#date-and-time-functions) but tedious.
Your approach relies on possibly unknown locale/user settings dependant date format.

From Win7 on Powershell is available as a tool:

On cmd line:

```
For /f "usebackq" %A in (`powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM\/yyyy')"`) Do Set Yesterday=%A
```

In a batch file:

```
For /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
    powershell -Nop -C "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('MM\/yyyy')"
`) Do Set Yesterday=%%A
Echo Yesterday=%Yesterday%
```

Modify the format string to your liking:

```
dd   = day   2 places
MM   = month 2 places
yyyy = year  4 places
```

Other characters have to be escaped with a backslash.